# How to get a connection string environment variable in an Azure function running locally?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to setup an Azure Function to run locally on my development environment. I wish to connect to a MongoDb database instance.

In my `local.settings.json` file I have added:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DB_CONNECT_STRING": "mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDatabase"
}
```

In my function I then have:

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    console.log(process.env.DB_CONNECT_STRING);
    context.done();
};
```

`process.env.DB_CONNECT_STRING` is undefined.

I assume I need to add some kind of prefix to the environment variable, but I can't find this documented anywhere. How do I specify a connection string and reference it in the function code?

Comment: Can you try `process.env.ConnectionStrings.DB_CONNECT_STRING` or `process.env.ConnectionStrings["DB_CONNECT_STRING"]`?

Comment: Both result in "cannot read property of undefined".

Comment: What happens if you add it in `Values` instead of `ConnectionStrings`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Matt Mason** is right.

In Node.js, we should specify app settings in the `Values` collection. These settings can then be read as environment variables by using `process.env`.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "DB_CONNECT_STRING": "mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDatabase"
  }
}
```

[image]

Then use `process.env.DB_CONNECT_STRING` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

For the purists out there, I found it. I set a breakpoint and evaluated "process.env" and found my connection string in this format:

```
ConnectionStrings:<ConnectionName>
```

[image]

So if my local.settings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "http://localhost:8080"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Prod": "MyConnString"
  }
}
```

Then I would access it like this:

```
 const sqlConnString = process.env['ConnectionStrings:Prod'];
```

You have to use bracket notation because of the colon.